# Delete skype group chat with Skype4com

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I have tried to make a function that will clear my Skype group chats.
Here is what I came up with:

1.

```
foreach (SKYPE4COMLib.GroupCollection d in skype.Groups)
{
    skype.DeleteGroup(d.Count);
}
```

2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < skype.Groups.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        skype.DeleteGroup(i);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Both approaches doesn't delete the groups. Not sure what needs to be done to remove all groups from my Skype.

Answer (score -1):

It can not be done via Skype4Com at the moment.

By the way, these groups that you are trying to delete are contact groups, i.e. you can group your contacts in Skype like in any address book. For group chats, look for Chat objects and check the chat member count, something like if (chat.Members.Count > 1).

You can find some more examples here: http://devforum.skype.com/

Comment: I know what to check, i just dont know the function to clear the group

Comment: You may not be able to delete chats at all, you can only leave chats, i.e. exit chats.

Comment: They are still on your recent chats, thats the whole pooint
foreach(Chat c in skype.Chats)
{
      c.Leave();
}

Doesn't do anything to fix my problem

Comment: Well, what you are asking, can not be done. I edited the answer. Theoretically the Chat.Disband() method should work, but it looks like the implementation is broken.